# How to add css class to style.css?

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code by helping of skobaljic which add title to class in div

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
 $("[title*='animotion']").addClass(function(){
  $(this).parent().css('overflow','visible'); 
  return $(this).attr('title');
 }).removeAttr('title');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" title="animotion newClass new1" /></p>
```

**How to add these new classes to style.css with jQuery?**

Comment: Check this out: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is - you don't do it that way.

Define the styles in the css file, then use the classes in the html - whether added inline or manipulated by jQuery - to attach the css rules to your html elements. Your css file doesn't change while in use. Your html document might change based on what javascript is being applied to it but the source file remains unchanged.